# Execution uglifyJs2 via Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I extracted uglifyJs2 via `uglifyjs --self` and I'm trying to minify app.js using uglify.js. I expect, that minified js should be generated into new file or console at least but now it doesn't work. What should I do to minify app.js using uglify.min.js?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
    bindings.put("console", System.console());
    executeJs("uglifyjs.min.js",scriptEngine, bindings);
    String res = (String) invocable.invokeFunction("UglifyJS.parse(code)", code);
   //Here I got NoSuchMethodException: No such function UglifyJS.parse(code)
}

static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
        throws IOException
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}

private static void executeJs(String fileName, ScriptEngine engine, Bindings bindings) throws Exception {
    String test = readFile(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    engine.put(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, fileName);
    engine.eval(test, bindings);
}
```

When i mo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

invokeFunction can be used to invoke only global functions. It can not be used to evaluate arbitrary code like you've above. The following will work:

```
// define a global function that accepts one arg and invoke UglifyJS.parse on it
scriptEngine.eval("function func(code) { return UglifyJS.parse(code) }");

// call the newly defined global function "func"
invocable.invokeFunction("func", code);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative...

```
    ScriptObjectMirror uglify = (ScriptObjectMirror)this.scriptEngine.eval("UglifyJS");
    String ugly = (String)uglify.callMember("parse", "mycode");
```

It does appear a wee bit slower in 100,000 calls of uglify.callMember(...) on my system its about 150ms slower. It didn't seem to make any improvement by first calling uglify.getMember("parse") and using call directly on that object.

It does however avoid a naming conflict